# Getting current windows session details using java desktop application

Tags: java, desktop-application, sessionid

I want to get the details of current logged user session details in a java desktop application.

Since i am new to java i am not able to get anything started in this case.

I have achieved the same using c# code.

The code is as below:

```
 var manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
            using (var server = manager.GetLocalServer())
           {
                server.Open();
                foreach (var session in server.GetSessions())
                {
                    if (session.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Active)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(session.ClientName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there something like this ,which is possible in JAVA too.

Please help.All help will be appreciated.